# How to run and debug apps script projects in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-apps-script, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-platform

After the Google Plugin for Eclipse has been deprecated the options are to install Cloud Tools for Eclipse and/or the GWT Eclipse Plugin:
[Developing Apps Script Projects in Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/apps_script)

I have installed both as recommended in Eclipse Oxygen but now I couldn't find a way to import Apps Script Projects from Google Drive.

Is this still possible or has been removed as a possibility?

If it's possible is there any documentation on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the plugin by Google.

Use the one from branflake instead : https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

On the github page there are links to excellent video tutorials of how to use this plugin : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU7ZQVLR5Zo&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT

Installation is done by simply clicking the install button on the github page under the "Marketplace" header.

Comment: By re-reading your question, this answer is probably not going to help you. AFAIK the branflake plugin is for GWT. I don't think it has support for the Apps Script projects...

Comment: That was I was afraid of, thanks for taking the time to have a look on this